# Generalized cohomology theory with coefficients and long exact sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, exact-sequence

Let $E$ be a spectrum, $A$ be an abelian group, and $M$ be the Moore-spectrum corresponding to $A$, i.e. $M_n = M(A, n)$, where $M(A, n)$ is the Moore space of $A$ in degree $n$. Then we get a new spectrum $E_A := M \wedge E$, and a corresponding cohomology theory $E(-; A)$, which is the cohomology theory $E$ with coefficients in $A$.
I want to prove the following: Suppose $q \in \mathbb{N}$ with $q > 2$, and $X$ is a topological space. Then there is a long exact exact sequence \begin{align*}
... \to E^n(X) \stackrel{\cdot q}{\to} E^n(X) \to E^n(X; \mathbb{F}_q) \to E^{n+1}(X) \to ... \end{align*}
Does anybody know a source for this statement or know how to prove it?

Comment: Smash the cofibration sequence $S^0 \xrightarrow{\times q} S^0 \to M(\mathbb{Z}/q)$ with $E$ to get another cofibration sequence, and then apply to $X$.

Comment: Do you mean a cofibration sequence of spectra? But $S^0$ is a space and $M(\mathbb{Z}/q)$ is a spectrum.

Comment: Yes, spectra, with $S^0$ denoting the sphere spectrum.